# In R, from a dataframe, how to split data into groups to plot multiple curves on the same graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a big dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(sb_data_omit_1950[sample(nrow(sb_data_omit_1950), 50),])
structure(list(lat = c("56", "61", "57", "59", "58", "56", "58", 
"65", "59", "65", "63", "65", "56", "59", "59", "57", "59", "60", 
"56", "57", "60", "65", "64", "63", "63", "59", "59", "65", "59", 
"58", "63", "59", "64", "59", "58", "59", "63", "56", "58", "59", 
"57", "55", "58", "64", "62", "60", "57", "58", "60", "66"), 
    long = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), date = c("2009-02-07", "1995-03-04", 
    "2007-01-28", "2010-03-28", "2010-04-01", "2018-02-22", "2017-03-24", 
    "2014-04-16", "1983-03-20", "2016-04-02", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-02", 
    "2005-03-25", "2003-03-22", "2016-04-02", "2006-03-19", "2009-04-05", 
    "2009-01-22", "2016-03-05", "2013-02-23", "2017-03-17", "2020-03-25", 
    "2021-03-27", "2008-04-08", "2018-04-10", "1984-04-04", "2005-01-29", 
    "2019-04-03", "1983-04-10", "2006-03-26", "2010-03-29", "2006-03-18", 
    "2014-05-06", "2010-01-23", "2006-03-26", "2014-02-25", "2008-04-16", 
    "2021-02-16", "2011-03-30", "2013-03-07", "1975-03-22", "2015-02-01", 
    "2013-03-21", "2011-04-07", "2021-04-06", "2021-02-02", "2000-03-19", 
    "1983-02-26", "2010-04-03", "2017-03-28"), julian_day = c(38, 
    63, 28, 87, 91, 53, 83, 106, 79, 93, 105, 93, 84, 81, 93, 
    78, 95, 22, 65, 54, 76, 85, 86, 99, 100, 95, 29, 93, 100, 
    85, 88, 77, 126, 23, 85, 56, 107, 47, 89, 66, 81, 32, 80, 
    97, 96, 33, 79, 57, 93, 87), year = c(2009L, 1995L, 2007L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2018L, 2017L, 2014L, 1983L, 2016L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2005L, 2003L, 2016L, 2006L, 2009L, 2009L, 2016L, 2013L, 2017L, 
    2020L, 2021L, 2008L, 2018L, 1984L, 2005L, 2019L, 1983L, 2006L, 
    2010L, 2006L, 2014L, 2010L, 2006L, 2014L, 2008L, 2021L, 2011L, 
    2013L, 1975L, 2015L, 2013L, 2011L, 2021L, 2021L, 2000L, 1983L, 
    2010L, 2017L), decade = c("2000-2009", "1990-1999", "2000-2009", 
    "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", 
    "1980-1989", "2010-2019", "2020-2029", "2020-2029", "2000-2009", 
    "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", 
    "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2020-2029", "2020-2029", 
    "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "1980-1989", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", 
    "1980-1989", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", 
    "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2020-2029", 
    "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "1970-1979", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", 
    "2010-2019", "2020-2029", "2020-2029", "2000-2009", "1980-1989", 
    "2010-2019", "2010-2019"), time = c(15L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 
    15L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 13L, 16L, 16L), lat_grouped = c("1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", "2", "3", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
    "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
    "3")), row.names = c(21286L, 5843L, 16479L, 24246L, 24483L, 
40513L, 39121L, 33554L, 2704L, 37376L, 48602L, 48008L, 12473L, 
9593L, 37380L, 14123L, 22712L, 21155L, 36663L, 29846L, 38722L, 
47518L, 51286L, 20119L, 42528L, 3132L, 11764L, 44966L, 2874L, 
14406L, 24290L, 14081L, 33634L, 23125L, 14393L, 31981L, 20790L, 
50057L, 26126L, 30068L, 1381L, 34000L, 30253L, 26612L, 51918L, 
49677L, 7640L, 2677L, 24745L, 39308L), class = "data.frame")

> head(df)
   lat long       date julian_day year    decade time lat_grouped
24  59   18 1951-03-22         81 1951 1950-1959   10           1
25  59   18 1951-04-08         98 1951 1950-1959   10           1
26  55   18 1952-02-03         34 1952 1950-1959   10           1
27  59   18 1952-03-08         68 1952 1950-1959   10           1
28  59   18 1953-02-22         53 1953 1950-1959   10           1
29  63   18 1953-03-12         71 1953 1950-1959   10           2
```

From this data, I would like to count the amount of observations per julian day (variable `julian_day`) in a given decade (two variables `decade` or `time` which is a numerical translation of the first one) and plot it against the data of other decades on the same graphic.

Until now, I have managed to plot the count of observations for all decades together using this code:

```
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=julian_day)) +
    geom_histogram(color="darkblue", fill="white", bins=152) +
    xlim(0, 155) +
    xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count")
```

I have the intuition that I should use a `group_by(time)` but cannot manage to plot some selected groups.

The output should look like multiple gaussian curves plotted on the same diagram.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much, if any information is missing I can edit my post :)

Comment: Thanks for adding your data, but they are all in the same decade since you just did `head(df, 20)` so hard to recreate your issue or help. Try randomly sampling your data with `dput(df[sample(nrow(df), 50),])` (for 50 observations)

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you need. It may be that all you need to do is move the color/fill into the `ggplot(aes()` call, like this :`ggplot(aes(x=julian_day, color=decade,fill=decade))`, and thus reduce the geom_histogram call to just this: `geom_histogram(bins=152)`. .Providing a more representative sample of your data, as suggested by @jpsmith would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your final output should be, but if you want all the histograms on one plot:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=julian_day, fill = decade)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=152) +
  xlim(0, 155) +
  xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

If you separate histograms on the same figure:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=julian_day, fill = decade)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=152) +
  xlim(0, 155) +
  xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count") +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free")
```

[image]

If you only want to select certain decades, you can add a `filter()` argument. The easiest way in this situation would be to filter by year, since it is numeric:

```
# first and last decade
keeps <- c(min(df$year), max(df$year))

# or any decade by referencing a year within that decade 
 # keeps <- c(2009, 1985)


df %>% filter(year %in% keeps) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=julian_day, fill = decade)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=152) +
  xlim(0, 155) +
  xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much for helping, is there a way to select some decades? for example if I want to plot only the first and last one? also, seing the results, I am wondering if a curve instead of an histogram should not be more appropriate..

Comment: See the edit - the plot itself is a user decision and isn't the subject of this question. These methods will work on histograms, lines, etc.

Comment: the method for selecting decades is perfect thanks! "the plot itself is a user decision and isn't the subject of this question" sure I understand, but I now think that a geom_curve is the most suited. I cannot make it work, would you know how to do it? :/

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** See comments:

We could combine `geom_histogram` applying count statistics with `geom_density` applying density statistics:

```
df %>% 
  count(decade, julian_day) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = julian_day, fill=decade)) + 
  stat_bin(bins = 30, aes(y = ..count..)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..density..*(nrow(df1)*0.8)), fill="yellow", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.3)
```

[image]
Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  count(decade, julian_day) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = julian_day, y=n, fill=decade))+
  geom_col(position= position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, I wonder if there is a possibility for making it more readable, to get a curve instead of columns?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Seems nice, but how do you divide by decades in order to get multiple density curves?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
df %>%
  count(decade, julian_day) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=julian_day, n)) +
  geom_line(color="darkblue") +
  xlim(0, 155) +
  xlab("Day n°") + 
  ylab("Count") +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: almost! except that it goes down to zero between each day. Is there a possibility to join only the top points?

Comment: @Recology it doesn't go to 0, it's hovering at 1